# Turn Signal Malfunction [2010 Ford Escape Hybrid]

Tags: ford, hybrid, turn-signal, escape

I have a 2010 Ford Escape Hybrid about a month back my right turn signal started to turn on randomly while the turn signal was in the neutral position. When this occurs turning the signal to the left turn position makes it turn off, but then the left signal would intermittently miss a blink.

At the worst point turning on the left signal would just turn off the right but not turn on the left.

Note: I took it to a dealer for them to look at and first they said they thought it was some module that needed replacement ($800 part & labor) then they said they think that won't work and it's the cluster (I think instrument) that is causing the issue ($1500 part & labor). So I just took the car home.

I honestly think based on how it's acting there's a physical part that is being pulled into the wrong position. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It seems to me the turn signal multi-switch is at fault. Part costs $70 and under on RockAuto.com. These are usually fairly easily replaced by the user. I'm not there, so cannot tell you for sure this is the issue, but sure seems that way from your description.

Comment: Did either of you find a solution? I’m having this problem and going crazy! Was it the smart junction box? I he steering column control module?

Answer (score 2):

After trying to solve this problem for months with my local mechanic, I had my dealer replace the Smart Junction Box, it’s been a week and my turn signals are back to normal. Total cost after tax was ~$600. After months of taking it to different mechanics and back and forth to the dealer it is so nice to have my car back to normal. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Check your basics is make sure the tail lamps are in good condition not fish tanks.  Make sure the correct bulbs are being used, check for water leaks in the rear/trunk.  Check the connectors.

Figure out if the lights are controlled electronically via a network of if they are hardwired.  Bizarre failures like this are usually electronic in origin.

Check the front lights too.  Also search TSBs carefully - exterior lighting is safety relevant and will trigger TSBs.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue on a Escape 2.5 2009. I changed the multiswitch; all it takes is to loosen the 3 5.5 mm bolts under the steering and pry off the two piece top cover. You now have access to to T 20 screws. remove and pull the unit to the left, disconnect the connector. put the new in in reverse order. Note, this didn't fix my issue, so I am back to the wiring diagram, I think this is very weird. I also cleaned the ground connections next to the battery, sanded the paint of the body and remounted using di-electric grease. Same issue. Maybe another bad ground. I did open the old multiswitch and it was overfilled with di-electric grease, that may cause some sort of a short. Try carrefully to open yours, remove excess grease, deep clean between the contact points and try it out. It is simple and take maybe half an hour and a cup of coffee.

Comment: This answer reveals two strategies (replace the multiswitch, and clean the switch's interior). The first one didn't work, and the second is merely a theory.

Comment: I never bothered trying to fix it, I just operate without a left turn signal.